Do Toyotas require alignment for rear wheels?
Brother's Camry having rapid wear on inside of tires. 2009 Camry. Do these require alignment in the rear?

Most vehicles on the road today don't have any alignment adjustment for the rear. There is the exception of high end sports cars, but realistically, they are far and few between. I'm not positive about your Camry, but would suggest it falls into the group which does not have an adjustment, with about a 99% assurity. If you find it is woefully out of adjustment, the problem is either something is worn or bent (or both). The best you can do is replace parts and you might bring it back into alignment. You can find in some extreme cases where the aftermarket has made provisions for adjustments, but those are pretty rare and usually relegated to those vehicles which are transformed into performance vehicles on a regular basis (ie: rear wheel drive drift cars).
